# Execute apex code after Bulk Data Load job is completed. Is that possible?

Tags: bulk-api

I want to run apex code after Bulk Data Load job is completed. Is that possible? I know we have a place to verify Bulk Data Load jobs and their statuses.

The thing is i have run an batch job on the data which has just loaded using Bulk API job. This should be work in an automated way. Means that if the client updates Bulk Job with status as "Close" then there should be some mechanism which will identify the status and trigger the batch program to run. The batch will do some cleanup work on the data loaded using Bulk Job. Any thoughts please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible?

No. There's no trigger mechanism at the end of a Bulk API load. You'll have to kick off such a batch job manually somehow.